# What does this scheme-val do?

Tags: scheme

```
#lang eopl

(define-datatype env env?
  (empty-env)
  (extended-env (var symbol?)
                (val scheme-val?)
                (envi env?)))

(define (scheme-val? x) #t)

; examples
(define e-env (empty-env))
(define e1 (extended-env 'x 1 (extended-env 'y #f e-env)))
```

I don't get how `scheme-val?` is used. Why is there an `x`, and why are we returning `#t`?
Environment is a function associating a variable with a value.

So in the example, we are associating `x = 1`, and `y = #f`, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scheme, `#t` is means boolean true, `#f` being false.  I don't fully understand the rest, but I suggest DrRacket's debugger to see what's going on.

```
(define e-env (empty-env))
```

assigns `e-env` to be an `empty-env`

```
(define (scheme-val? x) #t)
```

defines an anonymous function that takes a parameter `x`, and if it is a `scheme-val` (in this case, anything), returns `#t`.

The result of `e1` after this code runs is:

```
#(struct:extended-env x 1 #(struct:extended-env y #f #(struct:empty-env)))
```

so `e1` is an `extended-env with var='x, val=1, envi=(extended-env with var='y, val=#f, envi=e-env)`

(I think)

Comment: Thank you very much. The predicate `scheme-val` takes `x`, but in `env` , it is written in this form `var scheme-val?`, so I am guessing when we hit `define-datatype`, scheme knows to throw the variable on the left of the predicate as parameter of the predicate. Is that correct?

Comment: Don't confuse `define-datatype` with `define`.  In the `env` definition, specifically the `extended-env` definition, `val` is a `scheme-val`.  This `scheme-val?` operation is defined by the `(define (scheme-val? x) #t)` function, which returns true for any parameter `x`.  That's just the syntax.

Comment: Thank you. But where is the parameter x when we write `val scheme-val?` ? Is `val` passed into `scheme-val`? In other words, scheme interpreter is smart to notice that, since this is `datatype`, so the variable on the left is passed as parameter? I hope this clear up my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`scheme-val?` is a function that's supposed to return `#t` (true) if the value passed to it is of that type (in this case, a "scheme-val"). Just like `symbol?` returns true for symbols, and false for everything else, `scheme-val?` will return true for any object that is a scheme-val.

It turns out, that in this case, `scheme-val?` returns true for everything -- thus everything is a scheme-val. The `x` is there because the predicate is required to take a single argument, it's simply ignoring the argument and return `#t` for everything.

It's important in this case because you'll notice the `define-datatype`, it takes a value, and a predicate to check its type (`env` is the value, `env?` is the predicate).

Apparently `extended-env` also takes similar clauses. In this case, three of them: `var`, which is a `symbol?`, `val`, which is a `scheme-val?` and `env`, which is an `env?`.

Comment: Very nice :) thank you. The part `returns true for everything` is really helpful. Thanks!